# Why I am Getting Only One Post and Not All Posts by IDs

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I try to display posts by IDs on a page on Wordpress, the posts IDs are getten from a metabox value, i tried with this code:

```
<div class="grve-row grve-bookmark">
    <?php
    // Get the Instagram Post IDs from the custom metabox
    $instagram_post_ids = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'instagram_post_id', false);

    // Check if there are Instagram Post IDs
    if ($instagram_post_ids) :
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post', // Change to your post type if needed
            'post__in' => $instagram_post_ids,
            'orderby' => 'post__in',
        );

        $custom_query = new WP_Query($args);

        if ($custom_query->have_posts()) :
            while ($custom_query->have_posts()) : $custom_query->the_post();
    ?>
                <div class="wpb_column grve-column grve-bookmark grve-column-1-3">
                    <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
                        <div class="featured-image">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                <?php the_post_thumbnail(300, true); // Adjust image size as needed ?>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <h4 class="post-title">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
    <?php
            endwhile;
        else :
            // No posts found
        endif;

        // Reset post data
        wp_reset_postdata();
    else :
        // No Instagram Post IDs found
    endif;
    ?>
</div>
```

With this code for the metabox value [2204, 2218, 2187] I get only the post with the first id displayed, in this case the post with 2204 id is the only one displayed

How to get all posts displayed in stead of the only first one?

Comment: I'm assuming you are getting `2204, 2218, 2187` for your meta box, which when converted into an integer results in 2204. (If you actually had the square brackets around this, then converting it to an integer would result in 0, so you should not even get the first post from your list then.) You will need to `explode` this value at the comma-plus-space then, to get an array of individual IDs.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, how can I do this please?

Comment: `'post__in' => explode(', ', $instagram_post_ids),`

Answer (score 1):

One possible culprit could be the `posts_per_page` query parameter.

If the default value for it is `1` then you would have to change it.

For example, get 5 posts from the query:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post', // Change to your post type if needed
    'post__in' => $instagram_post_ids,
    'orderby' => 'post__in',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
);
```

Or you can use the value `-1` to return all posts, but beware of potential performance issues when you have a large number of posts.

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post', // Change to your post type if needed
        'post__in' => $instagram_post_ids,
        'orderby' => 'post__in',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    );
```

Comment: I added the query parameter 'posts_per_page', and still getting only one post